# Where is "volume sampling" options list in 2.76?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, interface, light, volumetrics

I am going crazy here, where is the option for the volume sampling in Cycles Render in the new Blender version? Normally you can choose either "Distance" or "Equiangular", I can't find it in the rendering settings!

It looks like this:

[image: There should be an options list]

But in the tutorial it looks like this:

[image: This is what it looks like in the tutorial video]

Can you help me please?

EDIT: Sorry, I meant "rendering settings", not "world settings". I changed it already.

Comment: The funniest thing is that you wrote it right the first time - this option indeed is in **World** > **Settings** rollout in new versions of Blender.